# Change in Sitecore Item saves only after clicking save button twice

Tags: sitecore-client

Recently I created a `custom Sitecore password field`. Though it works fine if any change is made in this custom field, the value does not get saved in a single Save button click. It asks to click save button again only then it saves the value.

I checked the code, everything looks good. So not able to figure out why it's behaving so. Has anyone else faced such an issue?

[image]

CODE FOR Custom Field

```
namespace Business.SitecoreExtensions.Fields
{
    public class Password : Text
    {
        public Password()
        {
            this.Password = true;
            this.Activation = true;
        }

        protected override bool LoadPostData(string value)
        {
            value = StringUtil.GetString(value);
            if (this.Value == value || this.Value.Replace("\n", string.Empty) == value || this.Value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty) == value)
                return false;
            this.Value = value;
            this.SetModified();
            return true;
        }

        protected override void SetModified()
        {
            base.SetModified();
            if (!this.TrackModified)
                return;
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Modified = true;
        }

        protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            this.Attributes["placeholder"] = Translate.Text(this.Placeholder);
            this.SetWidthAndHeightStyle();
            string str = this.TransformPasswordText();
            output.Write("<input" + this.ControlAttributes + str + ">");
            this.RenderChildren(output);
        }


        private string TransformPasswordText()
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            if (this.Password)
            {
                str = " type=\"password\"";
                try
                {
                    this.Attributes["value"] = new StringBuilder().Insert(0, "•", this.Attributes["value"] == null ? 0 : this.Attributes["value"].Length).ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Log.Warn("Could not resolve password length.", (object)this);
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                return str;
            return !this.Hidden ? "" : " type=\"hidden\"";
        }
    }
}
```

and Screenshot for Core database

[![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW0Wu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DApr0.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAmP0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAmP0.png)

Comment: Share the code and config for the field.

Comment: Edited the question to add Code and screenshot for Core database.

Comment: Is the issue present for other fields like Integrer or Number as well ?

Comment: No, the issue is for customized Password field only.

Comment: I see no registration in `<fieldTypes>` configuration. Did you omit this, or isn't it there?